# Create branch groups in Sourcetree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

My company insists on using Sourcetree and I am struggling to find out how to create groups and contain the branches in those groups, as the ORIGIN is getting messy as you can see here, the list is more than 3 times the items that are displayed in this screenshot. I tried looking for an option in the s/w itself and did research but I cannot find an option to do that.

[image]

Comment: Create a branch with a slash in it, e.g. `folder/branch`.  SourceTree will automatically format these as folders.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Is there a way to move already existing branches to the folder as well?

Comment: Found the way, all I have to do is checkout and rename the branches with folder/branchname and then push anything on the branch so that the remote gets update as well. Thanks, if you can post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a branch with a slash in it, e.g. `folder/branch`.  SourceTree will automatically format these as folders.

[image]